# É possível executar um aplicativo .EXE a partir de um Windows Service?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-service

**Este é um trecho do código:**

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\path\<file.exe>");
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
}
```

Eu gostaria de poder executar um programa .exe dentro do **onStart()**, porém, usando o método de **Process.Start()** não funciona. Tem outra forma de fazer isto? Caso sim, qual seria?

Comment: Não entendi o que você quer dizer com interno. Você quer que o seu windows service execute/abra outro programa ou que ele interaja com ele?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Isso não é possível.** Serviços do Windows não podem executar aplicativos executáveis ou invocá-los, diferente de aplicativos do Windows como Winforms, Console ou WPF. Seu código vai funcionar em qualquer aplicação que não seja um serviço do Windows.

O Windows tem um mecanismo de segurança com que faz que serviços sejam executados em sessões isoladas do contexto do usuário, portanto, não existe um contexto de onde iniciar o executável.

Executáveis do Windows somente são iniciados em um contexto, seja administrador, sistema ou qualquer usuário. Como um serviço não está em contexto específico, e sim uma sessão isolada, não há onde executar o aplicativo.

Existe uma maneira **insegura e não recomendada** de executar um executável a partir de um serviço: injetando o executável em um processo já existente. Portanto, isso pode tornar o sistema instável e passará a ser considerado um malware desde então. Mais detalhes [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40839708/4698166) do Stack Overflow.

Comment: Uhm, entendi. Obrigado amigo, muito esclarecedor. Vou analisar a resposta que você indicou.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:

<<**AVISO**>> **Não sei se vai funcionar pois Serviços possuem um mecanismo de isolamento que não permitem invocar janelas. Não sei se isso se aplica a processos sem janelas. Caso funcione de um retorno nos comentários**

Instancie a classe `Process` antes de usar o método [`Start`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.8) e use a propriedade [`StratInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow?view=netframework-4.8) para configurar a inicialização do processo.

```
   Process processo;

   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
   {
        try
        {
            processo = new Process()

            // Não exibe o shell
            processo.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            // Carrega o caminho do seu arquivo
            processo.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\path\<file.exe>";

            //Não criar janela de processo
            processo.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            // Inicializar o processo
            processo.Start();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
   }
```

Caso seu processo persista por todo o seu serviço:

```
   protected override void OnStop()
   {          
       processo.Kill();
   }
```

Comment: Primeiro, obrigado por responder. 

Sobre sua resposta, eu já havia tentado desta maneira porém não obtive sucesso.